# Swapping bits in assembly x8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I got homework for my assembly class that I got a problem while trying to solve it, here is the question:

"  Write a program that exchange D2 (2nd Bit) between DS:10H with DS:20H.  "

I tried to solve it with Shift Right but it doesn't seem good.

Comment: And now you expect that we do your homework for ya? Please provide some code. What did you tried so far?

Comment: Hey, i don't need you to do my homework, just need a way to solve this, you don't have to comment.

Comment: Please read this https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Shift right does shift bits right. While I can imagine solution of your problem using shift right (a bit artificially convoluted one), it can't be used as the only thing to solve the problem, needs quite some more instructions to support such construction. From the question it is not clear what your idea was, sounds more like you picked some instruction on random and wished it would work. Nope, just extract the desired bits from original values, then clear those places there, then put the other bit there (but preserving all others), which will end as "exchanged" 2nd bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way to solve this:

(For readability I use 4 bits in the example. So the letters a,b.. are bits, each having value 0 or 1.)

abcd AND 0010 gives the bit c:  00c0

pqrs AND 0010 gives r: 00r0

then:

abcd AND 1101 clears c: ab0d

ab0d OR  00r0 puts r in: abrd

similarly:

pqrs AND 1101 clears r: pq0s

pq0s OR  00c0 puts c in: pqcd

Comment: IIRC, you can use a modified xor-swap to do this slightly more efficiently: mask with `0b0010` after the first two `xor` operations or something, so it's a total of 4 bitwise ops to exchange 1 bit and preserve the rest.  If I'm remember that correctly; I didn't actually work it through. >.<